# Bazel Checkers Support

Tags: lint, bazel, static-code-analysis

What options do Bazel provide for creating new or extending existing targets that call C/C++-code checkers such as

- qac
- cppcheck
- iwyu

?

Do I need to use a `genrule` or is there some other target rule for that?

Is https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/extra-actions.html my only viable choice here?

In security critical software industries, such as aviation and automotive, it's very common to use the results of these calls to collect so called "metric reports".

In these cases, calls to such linters must have outputs that are further processed by the build actions of these metric report collectors. In such cases, I cannot find a useful way of reusing Bazel's "extra-actions". Ideas any one?

Answer (score 2):

I've written something which uses extra actions to generate a [compile_commands.json](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) file used by clang-tidy and other tools, and I'd like to do the same kind of thing for iwyu when I get around to it. I haven't used those other tools, but I assume they fit the same pattern too.

The basic idea is to run an extra action which generates some output for each file (aka C/C++ compilation command), and then find all the output files afterwards (outside of Bazel) and aggregate them. A reasonably complete example is [here](https://gist.github.com/bsilver8192/0115ee5d040bb601e3b7) for reference. Basically, the action listener (written in Python) decodes the extra action proto and extracts the source files, compiler options, etc:

```
action = extra_actions_base_pb2.ExtraActionInfo()
with open(argv[1], 'rb') as f:
  action.MergeFromString(f.read())
cpp_compile_info = action.Extensions[extra_actions_base_pb2.CppCompileInfo.cpp_compile_info]
compiler = cpp_compile_info.tool
options = ' '.join(cpp_compile_info.compiler_option)
source = cpp_compile_info.source_file
output = cpp_compile_info.output_file
print('%s %s -c %s -o %s' % (compiler, options, source, output))
```

If you give the extra action an [output template](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/extra-actions.html#extra_action.out_templates), then it can write that output to a file. If you give the output files distinctive names, you can find them all in the output tree and merge them together however you want.

A more sophisticated option is to use bazel query [--output=proto](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/query.html#output-formats) and write code to calculate the extra action output filenames of the targets you're interested in from there. That requires writing more code, but you don't have problems with old output files in the output tree that are accidentally included when aggregating.

FWIW, [Aspects](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/aspects.html) are another possibility. However, I think extra actions work acceptably for this.

Comment: I've added two extra actions here https://github.com/nordlow/build-system-benchmark/blob/master/BUILD and registered `cppcheck_cat` to be called upon `CCompile` (guessed name), `CcCompile` (guessed name), and `CppCompile` events. But I don't get any extra output when calling https://github.com/nordlow/build-system-benchmark/blob/master/test_bazel.sh eventhough its clear compiling. What have I missed?

Comment: You need to do the build with `--experimental_action_listener=//:cppcheck_c_cpp` passed to bazel.

Also, C and C++ will both be `CppCompile`.